# Changing the value of one object in an array is changing all of the objects in the array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, get, set

When I override get set in Objective-C, if this object is in an array, if I changed one of them's overrided property, all object in array has been changed

I have a class, named "Person":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *Name;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSDecimalNumber* Money;

-(instancetype)initWithName:(NSString*)name andMoney:(NSDecimalNumber*)money;
@end
```

in "Person.m", I override the get/set method of the "money" property:

```
   #import "Person.h"
    @implementation Person

    NSDecimalNumber* _Money;

    -(instancetype)initWithName:(NSString*)name andMoney:(NSDecimalNumber*)money{
        self = [super init];
        if(self){
            _Name = name;
            _Money = money;
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(NSDecimalNumber *)Money{
        return _Money;
    }

    -(void)setMoney:(NSDecimalNumber *)Money{
        _Money = Money;
    }

    @end
```

And now, i have an array with some persons:

```
NSMutableArray<Person*> *personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[personArray addObject:[[Person alloc]initWithName:@"11" andMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.1"]]];
[personArray addObject:[[Person alloc]initWithName:@"22" andMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.2"]]];
[personArray addObject:[[Person alloc]initWithName:@"33" andMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.3"]]];
[personArray addObject:[[Person alloc]initWithName:@"44" andMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.4"]]];
[personArray addObject:[[Person alloc]initWithName:@"55" andMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.5"]]];
[personArray addObject:[[Person alloc]initWithName:@"66" andMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.6"]]];
[personArray addObject:[[Person alloc]initWithName:@"77" andMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.7"]]];
[personArray addObject:[[Person alloc]initWithName:@"88" andMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.8"]]];
```

and now ,i changed one of person's money and name property:

```
[[personArray objectAtIndex:5]setMoney:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.22"]];

[[personArray objectAtIndex:5]setName:@"terry"];
```

and now, ALL OF the array's Person's money propery has been changed!!

```
for (Man* man in personArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@--%@",man.Name,man.Money);
}
```

every person in the array's money property's value is "0.22"!!

why??

Comment: thanks in advance! and sorry for my pool english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `NSDecimalNumber* _Money;` declaration is not an instance variable. It is a file-global variable. Since there is only one such variable, its value is used for all instances of your `Person` class. So it shows whatever value was set last.

You need to put the declaration in the `@implementation` block as follows:

```
@implementation Person {
    NSDecimalNumber* _Money;
}

// and the rest of your code

@end
```

FYI - variable names should start with lowercase letters:

```
NSDecimalNumber* _money;
```

Class names begin with uppercase letters.

Comment: Your answer is currect ! Thank you so much! I'm a C# coder 3 months ago and i have changed the spell to lowercase. thanks again!

Comment: @Terence And it is quite atypical to prefix with `_`.   And, really, there is no reason to declare the instance variable at all as described here.  It isn't wrong, it just isn't needed and is rarely done these days.

Comment: @bbum In Objective-C it is actually quite common to prefix ivars with an underscore to help avoid naming conflicts with property names.

Comment: @rmaddy  i think he  need not to override the get/set method of the "money" property again，because，If he don't `manual` override,  while system will help he to add get/set method by `default`.

Comment: @liangju No, there is no reason for the explicit setter and getter methods given the code in the question. I simply explained why the code wasn't working.

Comment: @rmaddy okay, i see.

Comment: Actually,this is my demo code. in my project, i have to do some other work in the Money property's "get" method.